# Using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to use Apache poi to read paragraphs in documents but there seems to always be another class missing that's needed by poi. Is there a way to include all the needed libraries or do I just keep running it and load in the next missing library?

Here's an example of how I'm tiring to read a .docx file.

```
public void toDITA(InputStream file) throws IOException{
    XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(file);

    Iterator docxIt = docx.getParagraphsIterator();
    while(docxIt.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(docxIt.next().toString());
    }
}
```

Update:
The errors are just classloader issues because certain jar files aren't there. I simply been downloading those missing jars and including them in the project's library, also I use Ant. I'm just wondering if there's a jar file that includes all these dependencies, or is there a feature in any IDE (I use NetBeans) that auto-downloads and includes these dependencies, kind of like how PyCharm with Python.

Comment: you are missing some dependency. What is the error you see?

Comment: Are you using maven or adding jars externally?

Comment: I use Ant with NetBeans, so I just include the jar files in the library.

Comment: @Christian, you need to download the jars and add to your library and, please ensure that the library is used in the classpath of your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are working with word documents.

HWPF is contained within the poi-scratchpad-XXX.jar, 
while XWPF is in the poi-ooxml-XXX.jar. You will need to ensure you include the appropriate jars (and their dependencies!) in your classpath to use HWPF or XWPF.

Please refer to this wonderful page, official documentation  [POI Offical Components Link](https://poi.apache.org/components/)

For Maven Stack that I personally use is

- poi
- poi-ooxml
- xmlbeans
- poi-ooxml-schemas
- ooxml-schemas

Comment: This doesn't require Maven, does it?

Comment: @Christian There are ways to do it. Either you add these jar dependencies by yourself into classpath and maintain the jar by yourself (download and add) or have a maven based project which takes care of the dependencies (download and add them to the classpath) you specify. so you just need to specify what you want and maven takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven then add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are adding jars externally. You can download all required list of jars from http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Minimum jar files you need to add :

- poi-ooxml
- poi
- commons-coded
- commons-collections4
- poi-ooxml-schemas
- xmlbeans
- stax-api
- curvesapi

Comment: You should refer to the most recent version and not some long outdated stuff